# How to show list data in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

I have a field **receiver_address** in my **Booking** Model I am storing list of address details as Road number, House number and Others. For example `['25 jalan', '35','Others']` 
Now i want to show data in my booking list.
My Django template code

```
{% for address in booking.receiver_address  %} address {% endfor %}
```

But it's not working. I am willing to see as like `25 jalan,35,others` in my booking list.
My present result in this [image: picture].

How can i get full address as `25 jalan,35,others`.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot define a list in django template, but you have to provide the list as an argument from you views.py – crodjer Dec 9 '10 at 5:45.
@dominic I meant he cannot initiate a list just like someone does in a normal python code, there are other ways to create lists in template otherwise.

Comment: I am taking a booking obj and sending from views.py and in my template view i have to show data from the obj attribute . how can i show then?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.